# Error use maketitle with Vietnamese

Tags: unicode, utf8, vietnamese

I have code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{spconf,amsmath,graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}

\title{BÁO CÁO TÌM HIỂU THÔNG SỐ TRONG DATASHEET CỦA DIODE}
\name{Name}
\address{\textbf{University}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

But it error **! Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte "C1.** and something like that.

If I edit the title "BÁO CÁO TÌM **HIEU** THÔNG **SÔ** TRONG DATASHEET **CUA** DIODE", it done.

Please help me, thank you.

Comment: Make sure that the file is indeed stored in UTF8

Comment: If you want someone to debug an error mssage do not paraphrase it "something like that" show the exact full mssage copied from the log file as text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file as posted in your question uses a non standard package, but using `article` it runs with no error if the file is used (as posted to this site) in UTF-8.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}

\title{BÁO CÁO TÌM HIỂU THÔNG SỐ TRONG DATASHEET CỦA DIODE}
\author{Name\\
\textbf{University}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you save the file in the legacy 8-bit VISCII encoding, you get

```
! LaTeX Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte "C1.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.10 \maketitle
               
?
```

Other non-UTF-8 encodings will give different errors, eg the alternative VSCII encoding gives

```
! LaTeX Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte "83.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.10 \maketitle
               
?
```

Comment: I'm using Texmaker. How can I do to solve this problem.

Comment: @MrCR I do not have that editor but it most likely has an option to save the file in UTF-8